# How to get the list of test methods from iOS IPA?

Tags: ios, reverse-engineering, xctest, xcuitest

I want to get the list of test methods from an IPA - XCTest or XCUITest.
Is there a way to get the list of XCUITest tests from an IPA?

Comment: I think IPA file generates from specific project target. XCTest and XCUITest are in the separate target. So they are not contains in IPA.

Comment: When you create the IPAs for testing, there are 2 IPAs. One contains the application and the XCTest tests, the other one is the XCUITest tests runner.